# Slow Query when I use Select in where Clause or inner join specific table

Tags: sql-server, performance, join

I have this query:

```
SELECT
    Tbl_Clientes.strNome as Cliente,
    Tbl_Clientes.strPostal as 'Código Postal',
    Tbl_Clientes.strLocalidade as Cidade,
    Mov_Venda_cab.dtmdata as 'Data Fatura',
    Tbl_Clientes.strNumContrib as 'N. Contribuinte',
    Mov_Venda_Lin.strCodArtigo as Artigo,
    Tbl_Gce_CondicoesCompra.strCodArtigoFornecedor as 'Artigo Fornecedor',
    Mov_Venda_Lin.strDescArtigo as 'Designação 1',
    Mov_Venda_Lin.fltQuantidade*mov_venda_cab.intSinal as 'Qtd. Faturada',
    Tbl_Gce_Artigos.strAbrevMedVnd as 'Unid. Venda',
    mov_venda_lin.fltvalorliquido/Mov_Venda_Lin.fltQuantidade as 'Prç.Liq.',
    mov_venda_lin.fltvalorliquido as 'Montante Liquido',
    Tbl_Gce_Vendedores.strnome as Vendedor
FROM 
    Mov_Venda_Lin
INNER JOIN 
    Tbl_Gce_ArtigosFamilias ON Mov_Venda_Lin.strCodArtigo = Tbl_Gce_ArtigosFamilias.strCodArtigo
INNER JOIN 
    Mov_Venda_Cab ON Mov_Venda_Cab.strCodSeccao = Mov_Venda_Lin.strCodSeccao
                  AND Mov_Venda_Cab.strAbrevTpDoc = Mov_Venda_Lin.strAbrevTpDoc
                  AND Mov_Venda_Cab.strCodExercicio = Mov_Venda_Lin.strCodExercicio
                  AND Mov_Venda_Cab.intNumero = Mov_Venda_Lin.INTNUMERO
INNER JOIN 
    Tbl_Clientes ON Tbl_Clientes.intCodigo = Mov_Venda_Cab.intCodEntidade
INNER JOIN 
    Tbl_Gce_CondicoesCompra ON Tbl_Gce_CondicoesCompra.strCodArtigo = Mov_Venda_Lin.strCodArtigo
                            AND Tbl_Gce_CondicoesCompra.intCodFornecedor = 124
INNER JOIN 
    Tbl_Gce_Artigos ON Tbl_Gce_Artigos.strcodigo = Mov_Venda_Lin.strCodArtigo
LEFT JOIN 
    Tbl_Gce_Vendedores ON Tbl_Gce_Vendedores.intcodigo = Mov_Venda_Cab.intcodvendedor
INNER JOIN
    Tbl_Tipos_Documentos ON Tbl_Tipos_Documentos.strAbreviatura = Mov_Venda_Cab.strAbrevTpDoc
```

Let's look at the `WHERE` clause:

```
 WHERE
     Mov_Venda_cab.dtmdata >= (select dtmUltimoEnvio 
                               from USR464_Tbl_GruposConsultas 
                               where codigo = 1 and bitInativo = 0)
     AND Mov_Venda_cab.dtmdata <= CONVERT(date, getdate())
     AND Tbl_Gce_ArtigosFamilias.strCodFamilia IN (17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29) 
     AND (tbl_clientes.CA_danone IS NULL OR tbl_clientes.ca_danone = 0)
     AND mov_venda_cab.bitAnulado = 0
     AND Tbl_Tipos_Documentos.bitAfectaVolumeVnd = 1
 ORDER BY 
     Mov_Venda_cab.dtmdata
```

I want to retrieve a date to this `where` clause and this date is on another table

If I execute

```
(select dtmUltimoEnvio from USR464_Tbl_GruposConsultas where codigo=1 and bitInativo=0)
```

This takes less than a second - but if I execute this whole query, it will take **11 seconds** that is too much.

In the `where` clause if I put a date filter manually (removing the select to the other table) the query executes in less than a second too.

For example:

```
WHERE
    Mov_Venda_cab.dtmdata >= '2015-01-01'
```

What I tried

Instead of making this

```
WHERE
        Mov_Venda_cab.dtmdata>=(select dtmUltimoEnvio from USR464_Tbl_GruposConsultas where codigo=1 and bitInativo=0)
```

I tried to Inner Join the table and use the field like this

```
inner join USR464_Tbl_GruposConsultas on
USR464_Tbl_GruposConsultas.bitInativo=0
and USR464_Tbl_GruposConsultas.codigo=1

WHERE
Mov_Venda_cab.dtmdata>=USR464_Tbl_GruposConsultas.dtmUltimoEnvio
```

But it also takes **11 seconds**

But if I declare a variable 1st like this

```
DECLARE @dataultimoenvio date
SET @dataultimoenvio = convert(date,(select top 1 dtmUltimoEnvio from USR464_Tbl_GruposConsultas where codigo=1 and bitInativo=0 ))
```

And then use the variable on the where clause like this

```
WHERE
Mov_Venda_cab.dtmdata>=@dataultimoenvio
```

This takes 3 seconds running .. and it's still too much .

3 seconds on my computer because on the computer that I want this query to run takes around 1 minute this 3 second query and 5 minutes the 11 seconds query.

Have you a better alternative to bring a variable from another table?

Why does every query separately runs in about 0.1 Seconds and together takes this long?

Comment: Take a look at the estimated execution plan by highlighting the query and then press Ctrl+L. This should give you an idea which part of the query is taking a long time.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to start using aliases in your queries. As posted your query is a wall of text and as such is nearly impossible to decipher. Also excluding aliases has been deprecated and will be required in the future. Here is your same query using aliases and some very rudimentary formatting.

```
SELECT
    c.strNome as Cliente,
    c.strPostal as 'Código Postal',
    c.strLocalidade as Cidade,
    mvc.dtmdata as 'Data Fatura',
    c.strNumContrib as 'N. Contribuinte',
    mvl.strCodArtigo as Artigo,
    cc.strCodArtigoFornecedor as 'Artigo Fornecedor',
    mvl.strDescArtigo as 'Designação 1',
    mvl.fltQuantidade*mvc.intSinal as 'Qtd. Faturada',
    ga.strAbrevMedVnd as 'Unid. Venda',
    mvl.fltvalorliquido/mvl.fltQuantidade as 'Prç.Liq.',
    mvl.fltvalorliquido as 'Montante Liquido',
    v.strnome as Vendedor
FROM Mov_Venda_Lin mvl
INNER JOIN Tbl_Gce_ArtigosFamilias af ON mvl.strCodArtigo = af.strCodArtigo
INNER JOIN Mov_Venda_Cab mvc ON mvc.strCodSeccao = mvl.strCodSeccao
    AND mvc.strAbrevTpDoc = mvl.strAbrevTpDoc
    AND mvc.strCodExercicio = mvl.strCodExercicio
    AND mvc.intNumero = mvl.INTNUMERO
INNER JOIN Tbl_Clientes c ON c.intCodigo = mvc.intCodEntidade
INNER JOIN Tbl_Gce_CondicoesCompra cc ON cc.strCodArtigo = mvl.strCodArtigo
    and cc.intCodFornecedor = 124
INNER JOIN Tbl_Gce_Artigos ga ON ga.strcodigo=mvl.strCodArtigo
LEFT JOIN Tbl_Gce_Vendedores v ON v.intcodigo=mvc.intcodvendedor
inner join Tbl_Tipos_Documentos d on d.strAbreviatura=mvc.strAbrevTpDoc
WHERE
    mvc.dtmdata >= (select dtmUltimoEnvio from USR464_Tbl_GruposConsultas where codigo = 1 and bitInativo = 0)
    AND mvc.dtmdata <= CONVERT(date, getdate())
    AND af.strCodFamilia in (17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29) 
    and (c.CA_danone is NULL or c.ca_danone = 0)
    and mvc.bitAnulado = 0
    and d.bitAfectaVolumeVnd = 1
order by mvc.dtmdata
```

I don't see anything glaringly obvious in there for a performance bottleneck. It is going to come down to table structure and indexing strategy most likely. At the very least an execution plan would help find the bottlenecks in here.